# Comandos personalizados en Linux

Tags: linux

Deseo crear un comando personalizado en linux, pero deseo usar otro comando dentro del mismo, en este caso deseo crear un comando que me muestre la version de angular, ayuda por favor. [image: Aqui muestro un ejemplo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes crear el script ejemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "angular version $(ng version)"
```

luego creas un link simbolico a la carpeta /bin o simplemente copiandolo
ejemplo:

```
ln -s /home/user/tu_scrip.sh /bin/ngv
cp /home/user/tu_scrip.sh /bin/ngv
```

con esto ya puedes llamar a `ngv` como un comando

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Byro No es recomendable editar a mano los archivos dentro de la carpeta `/bin` o agregar y eliminar elementos ya que, según `man 7 hier`, ahí sólo tienen que estar archivos exclusivamente para tareas administrativas o que permiten reparar el sistema en modo "single user", lo ideal sería en otra carpeta como `/usr/local/bin` o en `~/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

Primero que nada, para mandar a llamar un script y pasarlo como valor, necesitas pasarlo como command substitution, es decir, correr un programa dentro de $() o dentro de `` por ejemplo:

```
$echo "Hola $(whoami), haz estado aquí desde $(uptime -s)"
```

Entonces tu script podría ser así.

```
#!/bin/bash
A_VERSION="$(ng version)"
echo "Angular version $A_VERSION"
```

Entendiendo que las comillas preservan saltos de líneas, IFS y evitan ciertas expansiones.

Ahora, para que lo puedas llamar desde donde quieras puedes realizar varias acciones para obtener tu comando personalizado:

**~/bin**

Si es un programa que sólo vas a usar tú y sólo tú cuando estés loggeado en con tu usuario puedes crear una carpeta en tu directorio llamada bin, es decir `mkdir ~/bin`.

Dentro de esa carpeta creas tu script, llamémosle **custom_command**, que tenga el programa descrito anteriormente y le das permisos de ejecución, es decir, `chmod +x ~/bin/custom_command`

Luego añades a tu variable de ambiente PATH la ruta de esa carpeta, es decir

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

Y con esto ya lo puedes correr en esa sesión, si quieres que eso ocurre cada que abras la terminal, puedes poner ese mismo comando en tu archivo ~/.bashrc o ~/.zshrc (según la shell que uses). Dentro de ese archivo pones `PATH=$PATH:~/bin` y listo, cada vez que inicies sesión **sólo en tu usuario**, podrás teclear ese comando directamente y la consola lo reconocerá, incluso podrás agregar más comandos personalizados a la carpeta ~/bin. Si cambias de usuario no podrás utilizarlo. Esto te podría servir si andas realizando pruebas y no quieres que nadie más las vea por el momento.

**/usr/local/bin**

Si quieres que ese programa este disponible para todos los usuarios de esa distribución primero tienes que ver el contenido e la varible PATH con `echo $PATH` para que veas que la carpeta "/usr/local/bin" está añadida. Si esto es cierto (por lo general lo es), entonces puedes asegurar que puedes crear tu commando personalizado dentro de esa carpeta, es decir, el programa anterior lo pones dentro de `/usr/local/bin` como, por ejemplo, `/usr/local/bin/custom_command`, le vuelves a dar permisos de ejecución e, independientemente del usuario con el que te registres, puedes ejecutarlo.

Por lo general, mi recomendación es que tengas una carpeta de scripts personalizados, puede ser en tu $HOME o en /opt/, y de ahí crees enlaces simbólicos para /usr/local/bin

Es decir. En tu carpeta HOME creas una carpeta llamada $HOME/tools y dentro guardas los scripts como **custom_script**, les das permiso de ejecución con chmod +x, luego creas un enlace simbólico de cada uno de esos archivos a /usr/local/bin con `ln`. Ejemplo:

```
$chmod +x ~/tools/custom_script
$sudo ln -s ~/tools/custom_script /usr/local/bin/custom_script
```

Evita añadir o modificar archivos dentro de la carpeta `/bin` puesto que no corresponde a lo establecido en la jerarquía del sistema de archivos, puedes ver el manual al respecto con `man hier`.

Los programas dentro de `bin` únicamente son los que se ejecutan en modo de "single user" y son las herramientas básicas para reparar el sistema. Es decir, son programas exclusivamente para tareas básicas administrativas.

En cambio, los programas dentro de `/usr/local/bin` son para uso local de tu sistema, es decir, puedes añadir y eliminar archivos de ahí y no afectan las tareas básicas de tu distribución.

Answer (score 1):

Si sólo lo necesitas como un comando personal, para mí lo más sencillo y sin tocar las carpetas bin, es agregar un `alias` para el comando en tu `~/.bashrc` (o el correspondiente al tipo de shell que estés usando).

1. Edita el `.bashrc`:

   ```
   $ nano ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. Agrega el `alias` al final del documento:

   ```
   alias ngv='Angular Version: $(ng version)'
   ```
3. Guarda y cierra el archivo
4. Recarga la configuración

   ```
   $ source ~/.bashrc
   ```
5. Prueba el comando:

   ```
   $ ngv
   ```

Comment: puedes reiniciar el bash utilizando el comando source eje. source ~/.profile or source ~/.bash_profile para que lo agreges a tu respuesta!

Comment: @Bryro gracias!

Comment: Aunque `source ~/.profile` parece funcionar en este contexto en específico, realmente no se está reiniciando la shell. Lo ideal sería abrir una nueva shell interactiva (en caso de modificar archivos `.rc`) o volver a loguearse en el sistema (en caso de modificar archivos `.profile`) para que los cambios se propaguen correctamente. Por otro lado, faltaría un `echo` o `printf` en el alias pues como está actualmente `Angular` se ejecutaría como comando.

Comment: @Byro Sólo como aclaración, además de lo que contestó @nxnev, no se "reinicia bash" con `source ~/.profile` sino que `source` se encarga de cargar, en la terminal en curso el contenido del archivo, .profile o .bash_profile. Para "reiniciar" la terminal sería necesario ejecutar el comando `exec $SHELL` puesto que `exec` reemplaza la terminal activa con el comando dado, el cual es justamente el valor que tenga la variable `$SHELL`. Y ya una vez editados los archivos rc, que menciona @nxnev, ahora si se podría hablar de una especie de "reinicio", o al menos emularlo.

Comment: Este tipo de cosas son útiles, por ejemplo, en un caso específico que me ha pasado, instalar vía curl el sdk de google cloud pero no te quieres salir de tu consola porque la dirección en la que te encuentras es engorrosa de escribir, simplemente escribes `exec $SHELL` y se cargan las variables de entorno creadas por el instalador del sdk y que puso en algún archivo como .bashrc, etc.

Comment: @mrc_es ok, creo que ahora ya está claro